What does rigveda 8:25:18 said? It it refer to the flat earth?
Rigveda 8.25.18 claim that
(Mitra is he) who has measured with his rays the limits of both heaven and earth; who has filled bothheaven and earth with his greatness
So , what does the word "limits of heaven and earth" mean?

Scientific speculation isn't allowed on this site, but Vedic translations are the worse please refer to a good sanskrit dictionary for original meanings.
